# How to safely replace searches each with a replacement term where the former is part of the latter without running into replacing such a search again?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, match

```js
var string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
var stringArray = ["dashboard" , "dashboard" , "data"]
var replaceArray = ["https://abcd.com/login" , "https://abcd.com/home" , "https://abcd.com/data"]
for(i=0;i<stringArray.length; i++){
    string = string.replace(stringArray[i].trim(), "<a href='"+replaceArray[i].trim()+"'>"+stringArray[i].trim()+"</a>");
}
```

I have a string and 2 arrays like above. I need to replace my string with respective anchor link tags as mentioned in two arrays. stringArray defines the word to be linked and replaceArray defines the URL should be added. Like first occurrence of dashboard should be anchor linked with "https://abcd.com/login" and second occurance of "dashboard" should be replaced with "https://abcd.com/home" and "data" should be replaced with "https://abcd.com/data".

I tried to find out the word in string and replace it using replace/replaceAll, working fine for single occurrence word, but for multiple occurrences it is not working.

Anyone help me to resolve this.

Resulting :

```js
"Please click on <a href='https://abcd.com/login'><a href='https://abcd.com/home'>dashboard</a></a> and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the <a href='https://abcd.com/data'>data</a>"
```

**Expected Output:**

```js
"Please click on <a href='https://abcd.com/login'>dashboard</a> and then open the <a href='https://abcd.com/home'>dashboard</a> details to verify your details on the <a href='https://abcd.com/data'>data</a>"
```

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/replace-all-string-occurrences-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a string as the first parameter (substring) to the Javascript [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) function, `replace` will find and replace only the first occurrence of the substring. That's why both your "login" and "home" links are nested around the first occurrence of "dashboard", and the remaining occurrences of "dashboard" remain unchanged. Using a [regular expression as the first parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#defining_the_regular_expression_in_replace) is one solution, however not the only solution...

Using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to keep track of the last index where word from array `strArray` was matched, then [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)-ing the string after the last insertion to continue the replacement search from there:

```js
var string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
var stringArray = ["dashboard", "dashboard", "data"]
var replaceArray = ["https://abcd.com/login", "https://abcd.com/home", "https://abcd.com/data"]

// keep track of last position of matched string
let ii = 0;

for (i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
  let str = stringArray[i].trim();
  let repstr = '<a href="' + replaceArray[i].trim() + '">' + str + '</a>';

  // move position to index of matched string
  ii += string.slice(ii).indexOf(str);
  string = 
    // this is the portion of string before and including last replacement
    string.slice(0, ii) 
    // this is the portion after last replacement
    + string.slice(ii).replace(str, repstr);

  // move position to past current replacement
  ii += repstr.length;
}
console.log(string);
// Please click on <a href="https://abcd.com/login">dashboard</a> and then open the <a href="https://abcd.com/home">dashboard</a> details to verify your details on the <a href="https://abcd.com/data">data</a>
```

And this solution **benchmarks** about *120 times faster* than both the [regular expression solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72871317/2743458), and the reduce solutions I posted below.

---

Here's a solution combining the words and links into a single array, then using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the array `replace_arr`, update the string `string`, and maintain the match index `ii`:

```js
let string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
const replace_arr = [["dashboard", "https://abcd.com/login"], ["dashboard", "https://abcd.com/home"], ["data", "https://abcd.com/data"]];

replace_arr.reduce(
  (ii, [str, link]) => {
    let repstr = '<a href="' + link + '">' + str + '</a>';
    ii += string.slice(ii).indexOf(str);
    string = string.slice(0, ii) 
      + string.slice(ii).replace(str, repstr)
    return ii + repstr.length;
  }
  , 0
);

console.log(string);
// Please click on <a href="https://abcd.com/login">dashboard</a> and then open the <a href="https://abcd.com/home">dashboard</a> details to verify your details on the <a href="https://abcd.com/data">data</a>
```

---

Refactored reduction method for better performance—initially including `string` in the `reduce()` function, and processing internally, cuts execution time almost in half, compared to accessing the string externally to the reduction process with each iteration:

```js
let string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
const replace_arr = [["dashboard", "https://abcd.com/login"], ["dashboard", "https://abcd.com/home"], ["data", "https://abcd.com/data"]];

[string] = replace_arr.reduce(([ss, ii], [str, link]) => {
  let repstr = '<a href="' + link + '">' + str + '</a>';
  ii += ss.slice(ii).indexOf(str);
  return [ss.slice(0, ii) +
    ss.slice(ii).replace(str, repstr), ii + repstr.length
  ];
}, [string, 0]);

console.log(string);
// Please click on <a href="https://abcd.com/login">dashboard</a> and then open the <a href="https://abcd.com/home">dashboard</a> details to verify your details on the <a href="https://abcd.com/data">data</a>
```

...and this final solution benchmarks nearly twice as fast as the [regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72871317/2743458). :)

Comment: thank you, reduce solution is best suited for my use case..

Comment: @Siva_K22 ... There was nothing wrong with the above answer being the accepted one. I still consider a regex only approach not to be ideal. I upvoted *Vinicius'* solution just for the effort and the kind of discussion which lead to the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using a regex with lookaround:

```js
const text = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data or the other data";
const tokens = ["dashboard", "dashboard", "data", "data"]
const links = ["https://abcd.com/login", "https://abcd.com/home", "https://abcd.com/data", "https://abcd.com/dashboard/data"]

var result = text;

for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  const re = new RegExp('(?<=.*)((?<= )' + tokens[i] + '(?= |$))(?=.*)');
  result = result.replace(re, '<a href="' + links[i] + '">$&</a>'); //TODO array length validation
}

console.log(result)
```

This regex will only work for tokens surrounded by whitespaces to avoid replacing the texts inside URLs.

You can see more about lookahead and lookbehind [here](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind) and about browser compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).

Comment: Nope ... I tried this one at first place as well, but [the lookaround will fail for any url path which features an already replaced search term](https://regex101.com/r/vSPnk6/1). Also, lookbehind unfortunately still does not get supported by safari. One needs to come up with a more safe and more conventional approach.

Comment: @PeterSeliger pay attention that I used a negative lookahead (the (?!<) in the regex) to avoid this

Comment: I did, as I already said, I came up with exactly the same solution, but (...) ... Please have a look into the above linked example. It shows, that if one continues the search and replace for another (a 2nd) `"data"` it would match the one of the `href`'s path.

Comment: Just run the code in my answer and you will see that the result is correct

Comment: Please read carefully what I'm pointing to. The approach is not safe. Try it with two additional `"data"` related array items like with ... `const tokens = ["dashboard", "dashboard", "data", "data"];` ... `const links = ["https://abcd.com/login", "https://abcd.com/home", "https://abcd.com/data", "https://abcd.com/data"]` ... and the result will be broken.  Again, read carefully and please don't just argue.

Comment: Not arguing... The regex example in your link didn't have the token inside the URL as you exemplified now and it was not clear. Now I see it, maybe I can rewrite it to be safer, but it still can be a working solution without modification if you have control over your tokens.

Comment: But I'll delete the answer if I can't make it 100% safe.

Comment: nice ... [and approved](https://regex101.com/r/vSPnk6/2) ... deserves an upvote and a hint about https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: @PeterSeliger/@Vinicius 
@Peter Seliger, thank you. I have another use case, with an occurrences array , i only want to replace that specific occurrence word from the string. From below, 1 and 3 occurrences of dashboard and 2nd occurrence of data should be replaced. Can you help me with this.?
var string = var string = "On dashboard, then open dashboard details, verify your dashboard details on data and other data";
var wordsArray = ["dashboard", "dashboard", "data"]
var occurrences = [1 , 3 , 2]
var linksArray = ["https://abcd.com/login", "https://abcd.com/home", "https://abcd.com/data"]

Comment: @Siva_K22 ... I personally consider this one to already be another question. OP, please open another question where the problem gets described precisely, also with the expected result.

Comment: @PeterSeliger  -- Yea, but i resolved that with below RegEx.. 

string= string.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:.|\n)*?"+currentstring+"){"+occurence+"}"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp(currentstring+"$"), replaceString)});

Comment: @Siva_K22 ... Then the OP might consider posting an own answer with the altered/new requirement(s) and with an executable snippet in order to prove the OP's own new approach.

Comment: @Siva_K22 Can't you use better tokens inside your texts, like `{dashboard}` or `$dashboard`?

Comment: @Vinicius, Yes i can use, but there are many tokens which we dont know, comes from an excel workbook, i have to read the data and then display on webpage. Just for example i have added it like that.. Thanks for your effort..

Answer (score 0):

How about this one guy,

```js
var string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";
const stringArray = string.split(' ');
var targetTexts = ["dashboard" , "dashboard" , "data"]
var replaceTexts = ["https://abcd.com/login" , "https://abcd.com/home" , "https://abcd.com/data"]

const resultArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
  const word = stringArray[i];
  const targetTextIndex = targetTexts.indexOf(word);
  
  if (targetTextIndex > -1) {
    resultArray.push("<a href='"+replaceTexts[targetTextIndex]+"'>"+word+"</a>")
    targetTexts = targetTexts.filter((_el, idx) => idx !== targetTextIndex)
    replaceTexts = replaceTexts.filter((_el, idx) => idx !== targetTextIndex)

  } else {
    resultArray.push(word);
  }
}

console.log(resultArray.join(' '))
```

I hope you get a hint on this one.
It works like a charm, there will be exception handling for you to handle.

Comment: Thank you @yusung lee, it is as expected..

Answer (score 0):

The presented approach consists of

- a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task which firstly merges two related arrays, the list of search terms and the list of hypertext references, into another array of replacement items.
- a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) tasks which processes a list of replacement items and safely (without running into the same but already replaced search again) replaces each search by its related complete hypertext expression.

The 2nd part gets achieved by making use of the [`offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) parameter of the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method's [`replacerFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#parameters). Upon the `offset` value, the current matches index, one can programmatically (while *reducing*) split the originally provided string value into processed and unprocessed substrings/partials. The `reduce` task's array result gets [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)ed back into the final entirely replaced string value.

```js
function createReplacementItemFromBoundHrefs(search, idx) {
  const hrefList = this;
  return {
    search,
    href: hrefList[idx],
  }
}
function aggregateSafelyReplacedHrefPartials(partials, { search, href }) {
  // intentionally mutates `partials`, an array of zero to many
  // processed substrings and always an unprocessed (last item)
  // `target` substring of the originally provided string value.
  const target = partials.pop();

  let sliceAt;
  const result = target
    .replace(

      // a case insensitive search regex.
      RegExp(`${ search }`, 'i'),

      // a replacer function which helps preventing multiple
      // manipulations of always the same search/replace term.
      (match, offset) => {
        const replacement = `<a href="${ href }">${ match }</a>`;

        sliceAt = offset + replacement.length;

        return replacement;
      },
    );

  return [
    ...partials,              // - processed lately.
    result.slice(0, sliceAt), // - processed latest.
    result.slice(sliceAt),    // - to be processed.
  ];
}

function safelyReplaceSearchWithRelatedHref(str, searchList, hrefList) {
  return searchList
    .map(createReplacementItemFromBoundHrefs, hrefList)
    .reduce(aggregateSafelyReplacedHrefPartials, [str])
    .join('');
}

const string = "Please click on dashboard and then open the dashboard details to verify your details on the data";

const stringArray = [
  "dashboard",
  "dashboard",
  "data",
];
const replaceArray = [
  "https://abcd.com/login",
  "https://abcd.com/home",
  "https://abcd.com/data",
];

console.log(
  'before ... ',
  string,
  '\n\nafter ... ',
  safelyReplaceSearchWithRelatedHref(string, stringArray, replaceArray),
);
console.log(
  stringArray
    .map(createReplacementItemFromBoundHrefs, replaceArray) 
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> *"I have another use case, with an occurrences array , i only want to replace that specific occurrence word from the string. From below, 1 and 3 occurrences of dashboard and 2nd occurrence of data should be replaced. Can you help me with this.. ?? [...] `var string = 'On dashboard, then open dashboard details, verify your dashboard details on data and other data'; var wordsArray = ['dashboard', 'dashboard', 'data']; var occurrences = [1 , 3 , 2]; var linksArray = ['abcd.com/login', 'abcd.com/home', 'abcd.com/data'];`"* – Siva_K22

For this the above presented first solution could be easily refactored into a new one which keeps the two folded approach.

- The first task would be the creation of a replacement tracker which enables a replacer function to keep track of each search's current occurrence count and replacement.
- The second task straightforwardly does [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the provided original string via

  - a case insensitive regex which features any possible word/search ... and ...
  - a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#parameters) which keeps track of each search's occurrence and upon a search's current occurrence count decides whether to really replace a search by its related full hypertext reference or just with itself (its very own match).

> *"@PeterSeliger -- Yea, but i resolved that with below RegEx.. string= string.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:.|\n)*?"+currentstring+"){"+occurence+"}"), function(x){return x.replace(RegExp(currentstring+"$"), replaceString)});"* – Siva_K22

Again a regex only approach will never be as reliable (also not as readable) as one that truly tracks search occurrences and was implemented with both goals being generic on one hand but also specialized enough (a regex only approach is limited much earlier in the latter terms).

```js
function aggregateReplacementTrackerFromBoundData(collector, search, idx) {
  const { occurrences = [], hrefList = [], tracker = {} } = collector;

  // create and/or access and aggregate
  // a search specific occurrence tracker.
  (tracker[search.toLowerCase()] ??= {
    occurrence: {},
    occurrenceCount: 0,
  })
  .occurrence[ occurrences[idx] ] = hrefList[idx];

  return { occurrences, hrefList, tracker };
}
function safelyReplaceSearchOccurrencesWithRelatedHref(
  str, searchList, hrefList, occurrences,
) {
  // create an overall replacement tracker for any search.
  const { tracker } = searchList
    .reduce(aggregateReplacementTrackerFromBoundData, {
      occurrences,
      hrefList,
      tracker: {},
    });

  return str
    .replace(

      // a case insensitive regex which features any possible word/search.
      RegExp(`\\b(?:${ searchList.join('|') })\\b`, 'gi'),

      // a replacer function which keeps track of each search's occurrence
      // and upon a search's current occurrence count decides whether to
      // really replace a search by its related full hypertext reference
      // or just with itself (its very own match).
      (match/*, offset, target*/) => {
        const searchTracker = tracker[match.toLowerCase()];

        const count = ++searchTracker.occurrenceCount;
        const href = searchTracker.occurrence[count] ?? null;

        return (href !== null)
          && `<a href="${ href }">${ match }</a>`
          || match;
      },
    );
}

const string = "On dashboard, then open dashboard details, verify your dashboard details on data and other data";

const wordsArray = [
  "dashboard",
  "dashboard",
  "data",
];
const occurrences = [1 , 3 , 2];

const linksArray = [
  "https://abcd.com/login",
  "https://abcd.com/home",
  "https://abcd.com/data",
];

console.log(
  'before ... ',
  string,
  '\n\nafter ... ',
  safelyReplaceSearchOccurrencesWithRelatedHref(
    string, wordsArray, linksArray, occurrences,
  ),
);
console.log({
  replacementTracker: wordsArray
    .reduce(aggregateReplacementTrackerFromBoundData, {
      occurrences,
      hrefList: linksArray,
      tracker: {},
    })
    .tracker
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thank you. I have another use case, with an occurrences array , i only want to replace that specific occurrence word from the string. From below, 1 and 3 occurrences of dashboard and 2nd occurrence of data should be replaced. Can you help me with this.. ??

var string = var string = "On dashboard, then open dashboard details, verify your dashboard details on data and other data";
var wordsArray = ["dashboard", "dashboard", "data"]
var occurrences = [1 , 3 , 2]
var linksArray = ["https://abcd.com/login", "https://abcd.com/home", "https://abcd.com/data"]

Comment: @Siva_K22 ... Since the OP is a member for just 31 days and the inter/actions at the OP's questions hint towards most probably just two accepted answers the question arises whether the OP is aware of any answer's [voting option](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (down/up ... "This answer is not/useful"). Though being thanked twice is a nice gesture, I wouldn't mind being rewarded for all the effort especially for providing the only solution for the OP's actually 2nd question with an entirely change requirement set. Also the OP meanwhile earned the voting privilege.